# Create sub array of duplicates and randomize order c#

Tags: c#

I am returning a list of items from the Database. List contains info like id, first name, last name, # of sales, $ revenue.

```
1 John James 431 213000
2 Scott Smith 301 43000
3 Jane Doe 431 300000
4 Tess Jones 431 14280
```

my results will contain the 4 rows as shown above. I am ordering my rows in descending order based on the # sales value. If the # sales value is the same then I order by id. So after ordering my results will look like so:

```
3 Jane Doe 431 300000
1 John James 431 213000
4 Tess Jones 431 14280
2 Scott Smith 301 43000
```

Now I would like to randomize the order of the rows where the #sales are the same. I am sure that means that I probably won't use the order by id.

How can I create a subarray of my results where the #sales are the same and then randomize their order and insert it to the original array? The main reason I am doing this is to add some variety to the data I will display so it not the same and gives the users the opportunity to be displayed in a different order.

This is how i am getting my original data:

```
results = results.OrderByDescending(x => Math.Max((uint)x.TotalSales, x.TotalRevenue))
                            .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                            .Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

I believe I will be applying the randomizing part as follows:

```
var randomIndx= new Random(TotalSales).Next(100) % (#: will this be the number of duplicates?);
```

so that

I am not sure how to put things together. Any helpful tips are much appreciated.

Comment: Why do people vote down without explaining why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply an ordering to your collection using `Random`, which will shuffle the results. Using `ThenBy` will ensure that entries are shuffled only within their previous-level ordering (items will be shuffled within their same "NumOfSales").

For example, with class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public int NumOfSales{get;set;}
    public int Revenue{get;set;}
}
```

Your code could look like this:

```
var originalEmployeeList = new List<Employee>()
{
    new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "John James", NumOfSales = 431, Revenue = 213000 },
    new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "Scott Smith", NumOfSales = 301, Revenue = 43000 },
    new Employee { Id = 3, Name = "Jane Doe", NumOfSales = 431, Revenue = 300000 },
    new Employee { Id = 4, Name = "Tess Jones", NumOfSales = 431, Revenue = 14280 },
};

var random = new Random();
var randomizedResults = originalEmployeeList
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.NumOfSales)
    .ThenBy(x => random.Next())
    .ToList();
```

The key here is using `random.Next()` INSIDE a `ThenBy`. With this example, people with a NumOfSales = 431 will always appear before people with a NumOfSales = 301, but the listing of people within the same NumOfSales will be randomized.

Here's a runnable example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/W2ESGt

Comment: Really appreciate the explanation. This worked great and I learned something new. Turned out much simpler than I anticipated.  Thank you.